# python generator invalid literal for int()

Tags: python, linux

i am using the field-map generator function from http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/fieldmap.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def field_map(dictseq, name, func):
    for d in dictseq:
        d[name] = func(d[name])
        yield d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loglines = open("test.log")
    import re
    logpats = r'(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[(.*?)\] \"(.*?)\" (\S+) (\S+) \"(.*?)\" \"(.*?)\" (\S+) \"(.*?)\" \"(.*?)\" (\S+)'
    logpat = re.compile(logpats)
    groups = (logpat.match(line) for line in loglines)
    tuples = (g.groups() for g in groups if g)
    #for t in tuples:
    #    print t

    colnames = ('record_id', 'elapsed_time', 'client', 'username' , 'client_id','date',
                'http_method_url', 'status', 'size', 'http_referer','useragent', 'mime',
                'filter_name_reason', 'profiles', 'ipport')
    log = (dict(zip(colnames,t)) for t in tuples)
    log = field_map(log,"status",int)
    log = field_map(log,"size",lambda s: int(s) if s != '-' else 0)
    for x in log:
        print x
```

its gives this error, any ideas?

```
[root@cumbria extended]# python fieldmap.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fieldmap.py", line 24, in <module>
    for x in log:
  File "fieldmap.py", line 4, in field_map
    for d in dictseq:
  File "fieldmap.py", line 5, in field_map
    d[name] = func(d[name])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'status'
```

test.log has data in this format

```
"1356313509.519-6-10.66.54.21-8080" 2089 10.112.151.213 "anonymous@10.112.151.213" "6" [24/Dec/2012:01:45:11] "GET http://apps.facebook.com:80/thesimssocial/?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=2&fb_bmpos=4_2" 200 58300 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11 BMID/E679E9E153" text/html "- -" "M&B-112,HTTP,QUERIES,uncachable,antivirus,REDIRECT_THIS" "10.66.54.21:8080"
```

Comment: `int()` is a builtin fucntion and it expects only integers containing strings. why are you passing `int` to the function `field_map`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Passing `int` makes sense here, `field_map` is a weird kind of `map()` with side effects.

Comment: test.log contains the proxy logs and the regular expressions match successfully

Comment: @krisdigitx I'm pretty sure your data isn't what you think it is. For one, give us some test data that shows the problem so we can run the test, and also `print tuples` so we can see what data is there.

Comment: Also note that your log file seems to be space separated values - in which case the `csv` module could probably parse your data for you.

Comment: added the test.log, i found the problem the first line in test.log did not match the format, after removing it, it worked fine...

Answer (score 1):

The first line in test.log is probably a header that contains field names instead of their values. That is why you see "status" instead of e.g., "200".

You could make your regex more selective to filter out inappropriate line sooner e.g., use `\d+` to match http status.